# What does "ERROR - Can't compile non template nodes" in Airflow with the PapermillOperator mean?

Tags: airflow, papermill

I'm running my first Papermill task, which is to run a Jupyter notebook. Here is the operator:

```
t5 = PapermillOperator(
    task_id="run_example_notebook",
    input_nb=path2,
    output_nb=path2,
    parameters={"msgs": "Ran from Airflow at {{ execution_date }}!"},
    dag=dag,
)
```

I think the file path is correct:

```
path2 = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../amazon_visualization3.ipynb')
```

Then, the following error occurs:

```
ERROR - Can't compile non template nodes
```

Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I have the same issue on GCP. My research says it's a problem between the parameters argument passed to the operator and when the same parameter is to be used by jinja. I haven't seen a solution yet. If anyone can help, that would be great